# Not able to open lightning component from quick action otherwise working fine

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, quickaction, lightning-quickaction

i get the record id alert after that nothing works

```
 doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    alert('start'+component.get("v.recordId"));
    var action1 = component.get("c.getCurrentOpp");
    alert('start2');
    action1.setParams({ "oppId":component.get("v.recordId") });
    action1.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state1 = response.getState();
            if(state1 == "SUCCESS"){
            //component.find("stage").set("v.disabled", true);
            component.set("v.opportunity", response.getReturnValue());
        }else if(state1 == "ERROR"){
            alert('Error : ' + JSON.stringify(response.getError()));
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action1);

    var opts = [
        { class: "optionClass", label: "--None--", value: "", selected: "true" },
        { class: "optionClass", label: "Non Payment", value: "Non Payment", selected: "true" },
        { class: "optionClass", label: "Graduate", value: "Graduate" },
        { class: "optionClass", label: "Can't Afford Program", value: "Can't Afford Program" }

    ];
    component.find("InputSelectDynamic").set("v.options", opts);
}
```

I get this error

> Unfortunately, there was a problem. Please try again. If the problem
>   continues, get in touch with your administrator with the error ID
>   shown here and any other related details. Action failed:
>   forceChatter:lightningComponent$controller$doInit [Error while
>   creating content for lightning component quick action]
>   quickActionHandlerHelper.js failed to create component -
>   forceChatter:lightningComponent

Comment: I'm not sure, but it might be the "selected" attribute; it should be `selected: true`, not `selected: "true"`. The difference is that one is a Boolean, the other is a String.

Comment: Can you post relevant component code and also apex controller code?